# Altcoin connecting nodes

Tags: litecoin

I have created my crypto currency based on Litecoin 0.13.2.
All seem works fine except fact that nodes are not synchronizing.

Debug says:

> Ignoring getheaders from peer=x because is in initial block download.

If I compile version 0.8.x and connect to 0.13 there is no problem with blocks data interchange.

I have mined few blocks for testing but stil getting same error, therefore I cannot run my network.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your node thinks it is in initial block download.

There are several reasons why that might happen, but I think only two apply here.

- The chain tip is more than `nMaxTipAge` seconds old. Try setting the `-maxtipage` option to a big number, and see if that fixes it.
- The chain tip has less than `nMinimumChainWork` (from `chainparams.cpp`) of work put into it.

---

Here are the conditions that trigger initial block download:

```
bool IsInitialBlockDownload()
{
    const CChainParams& chainParams = Params();

    // Once this function has returned false, it must remain false.
    static std::atomic<bool> latchToFalse{false};
    // Optimization: pre-test latch before taking the lock.
    if (latchToFalse.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
        return false;

    LOCK(cs_main);
    if (latchToFalse.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
        return false;
    if (fImporting || fReindex)
        return true;
    if (chainActive.Tip() == NULL)
        return true;
    if (chainActive.Tip()->nChainWork < UintToArith256(chainParams.GetConsensus().nMinimumChainWork))
        return true;
    if (chainActive.Tip()->GetBlockTime() < (GetTime() - nMaxTipAge))
        return true;
    latchToFalse.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this maybe related to ammount of blocks.
I used old code to mine a block, maybe this is an issue too?
Do you know the right way how to premine ?

Comment: OK, possible I took right assumption.
However still not sychronize. I have generated ~100 blocks and the second node can see it "Received satoshi...block: 100" but then do nothing...
Debug file says: getheaders -1 to 000000...